# Laravel - Send Notifications via Job class - Enqueueing Notifications to redis queue without sending them twice

Tags: php, laravel, redis, queue, jobs

I want to enqueue notifications to redis queue via a job class.
I ask myself what is the best practice to send notifications via a job and not sending them multiple times. My job is triggered by an artisan command which is triggered every minute to grab and send the latest notifications from database. My fear is that the notification query lasts too long, so the job which grabs the notification hasn'nt finished yet until the next notification sending job is triggered and partly sends the same notifications. Should I put an additional flag in my notifications table to mark notifications as queued or can you solve this anyhow by using redis cache?
Best regards

Answer (score 2):

Best practice with jobs is to make them idempotent. Which means even if the same job is ran multiple times, there are no side effects from it. In this case that would mean sending the same notification twice. Usually this is achieved by setting something in the db that the notification has been picked up.

Answer (score 1):

The additional flag makes the most sense. As soon as you grab a notification to process, flag it as taken.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's schedule event objects have a [`withoutOverlapping`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html#method_withoutOverlapping) method you could to ensure that a job is run until completion before the next one is allowed to start. You can use it like this:

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->withoutOverlapping();
```

It think it should work the same way for scheduling jobs, e.g.:

```
$schedule->job(new Heartbeat)->everyFiveMinutes()->withoutOverlapping();
```

The [Preventing Task Overlaps](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps) documentation contains some more information.